# update value from '0' to '1' on image click?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php and mysql so sorry if i'm doing it wrong. i have a page on my site that lists the reviews that members give to other other users.

Basically i have approved and deleted in my database which means that after a user sends the review it has to be reviewed by the user before it gets displayed.

once the user clicks the approved image which is a tick it goes to approved_review.php and in their i have my sql code to update the value from 0 to 1 in my database.

It should work exactly the same for the delete but obviously instead of updating the approved column it will update deleted.

the code i have tried is not working i have been working on this for quite some time and can;t figure it out.

Can someone please tell me where i'm going wrong?

Heres the code:

```
<?php
    $reviews_set = get_pending_reviews();
    while ($reviews = mysql_fetch_array($reviews_set)) {    
?>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="pending-review-content">
<?php 
    $date = $reviews['date_added'];
?>
    <div class="prof-content-pend-reviews" id="reviews">
        <div class="message_pic"><?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$reviews['from_user_id']}\">
        <img width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\" src=\"data/photos/{$reviews['from_user_id']}/_default.jpg\" /></a>";?>
    </div>

    <div class="reviews-date"><? echo "$date"; ?></div>
    <div class="reviews-from">
        <?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$reviews['from_user_id']}\">{$reviews['display_name']}"; ?>
        </a> Wrote:
    </div>
    <div class="reviews-content">
        <?php echo "{$reviews['content']}"; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="reviews-approve">    
    <a href="includes/approved_review.php"><img src="assets/img/icons/tick.png" width="30" height="25" /></a></div>
    <div class="reviews-delete">
    <a href="includes/delete_review.php"><img src="assets/img/icons/cross.png" width="30" height="25" /></a>
</div>

<? } ?>
```

approved_review.php function:

```
<?
    $sql = "UPDATE  `playtime`.`ptb_reviews` SET  `approved` =  '1' WHERE `ptb_reviews`.`id` =".$_SESSION['user_id']."";

    echo "<div class=\"infobox1\">review approved.</div>";

?>
```

Comment: please clear your question ... Are you tring to do this by form or ajax ... also you are not checking that box is ticked/marked  ..

Comment: what box? he seems wants the user to click on the anchor with `href=includes/approved_review.php`. But still, there is a lot of code missing to find out what's going on. Please provide more details! (e.g. where do you set the SESSION variable userid, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems logical. After you loop through your reviews, you click on the tick or delete pngs to update or delete.

So, in `approved_review.php`

```
<?php 

//you are missing the connection to your mysql database...
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$sql = "UPDATE  `playtime`.`ptb_reviews` SET  `approved` =  '1' WHERE `ptb_reviews`.`id` =".$_SESSION['user_id']."";

//execute the mysql query
$r = mysql_query($sql);


if (!mysql_error())
{
    echo "<div class=\"infobox1\">Review Approved.</div>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

a little edit rrrfusco's post

```
// or die for details if mysql_query won't work correct
$r = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```